# How to remove black debug boxes from DirectX 11 and XAML app

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, windows-10

I have created an app from *"DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows)"* template in MSVC. When I launch it, I see a black box with white letters at the top left corner of the app window. Also, similar box appears at the right top corner of my display.

[image]

I guess it is sort of debug output, but I do not know how to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a setting that is only enabled for debugging indeed, more info about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.debugsettings.enableframeratecounter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

I don't have it when I start a new DirectX 11 project in Visual Studio 2015 (maybe it's removed in the new templates). You should look for `DebugSettings->EnableFrameRateCounter = true` and set that flag to false.